# controlling a dc motor using microprocessor

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, intel, microprocessors

MTS-88.C board  has an intel 8255 PPI connected with microprocessor 8088 at address 000100xxb. Top portion of the board includes connectors  CN01-CN09 and LED01 –LED08. LED01 is internally connected to CN0(i+1). Each of CN02-CN09 has two connecting terminal – one is directly connected to GND and the other is connected to +12v power supply through push button switch.

PBi is connected to LED (16-i) and Relay RLi is connected to CN (9+i). So PBi controls CN (17-i). Each of CN10 to CN17 contains three connecting terminals- labeled NO (normally open), COM and NC (normally close). NO is connected to GND, NC to +12V supply and COM  terminals can be used to drive 12V DC or Stepper motor or other devices that need 12V power supply.

The following assembly program controls the rotational direction of DC motor based on key press (three push buttons) in the following way:

P1: Clockwise

P2: Anti-clockwise

P3: Stop

Assembly program:

```
Address     Assembly Code   
0000:0400       MOV AL,90   
0000: 0402      OUT 13,AL   
0000: 0404      MOV AL,00   
0000: 0408      IN AL,10    
0000: 040A      CMP AL,FE   //what are we checking here?
0000: 040C      JNE 419 
0000: 040E      MOV AL,00  //why are we assigning 00?   
0000: 0410      OUT 11,AL   
0000: 0412      MOV AL,02  //why are we using 02?
0000: 0414      OUT 11,AL   
0000: 0416      JMP 500 
0000: 0419      CMP AL,FB   //what are we checking here?    
0000: 041B      JNE 428 
0000: 041D      MOV AL,00   //why are we assigning this?    
0000: 041F      OUT 11,AL   
0000: 0421      MOV AL,01   //why are we using 01?
0000: 0423      OUT 11,AL   
0000: 0425      JMP 500 
0000: 0428      CMP AL,FD   //what are we checking here?    
0000: 042A      JNE 408 
0000: 042C      MOV AL,00   
0000: 042E      OUT 11,AL   
0000: 0430      JMP 500 
0000: 0433      INT 3
0000: 0500      MOV CX,100  
0000: 0503      LOP 0503    
0000: 0505      JMP 408 
0000: 0508      INT 3
```

I have some confusions about the code which I have marked through comments in the above code. And my other question is how the motor is moving clockwise and anticlockwise? and what is the function if relay here?

Answer (score 0):

I have added some comments

```
Address     Assembly Code   
0000:0400       MOV AL,90   
0000: 0402      OUT 13,AL   
0000: 0404      MOV AL,00   
0000: 0408      IN AL,10    
0000: 040A      CMP AL,FE   // check "Forward" key press (active low)
0000: 040C      JNE 419 
0000: 040E      MOV AL,00   // turn off outputs (active high)
0000: 0410      OUT 11,AL   
0000: 0412      MOV AL,02   // turn on output 2 (active high)
0000: 0414      OUT 11,AL   
0000: 0416      JMP 500 
0000: 0419      CMP AL,FB   // check "Reverse" key press (active low)
0000: 041B      JNE 428 
0000: 041D      MOV AL,00   // turn off outputs (active high)
0000: 041F      OUT 11,AL   
0000: 0421      MOV AL,01   // turn on output 1 (active high)
0000: 0423      OUT 11,AL   
0000: 0425      JMP 500 
0000: 0428      CMP AL,FD   // check "Stop" key press (active low)
0000: 042A      JNE 408 
0000: 042C      MOV AL,00   // turn off outputs (active high)
0000: 042E      OUT 11,AL   
0000: 0430      JMP 500 
0000: 0433      INT 3
0000: 0500      MOV CX,100  // software delay
0000: 0503      LOP 0503    
0000: 0505      JMP 408 
0000: 0508      INT 3
```

Comment: what is the meaning of turn on/off output? and how the motor is moving clockwise and anti clockwise when the push button is pressed? will you please explain? @Weather Vane

Comment: Like a light bulb: turn on / turn off: I suppose there is one output for "forward" and one output for "reverse". I also guess that the code turns all outputs off before enabling another, is to ensure there can never be any "fight" between forward and reverse.

Comment: what is the basic principle used here for anticlockwise moving? How this is working when I am pressing button 2?@Weather Vane

Comment: I suggest you get out a 'scope and take a look at pin levels. I don't have the hardware you are showing code for.

Comment: when I am using MOV AL,01 or, MOV AL,02 for turning on  output 1 or 2, I am just setting a bit each time on port B.. right? but why just one bit? @Weather Vane

Comment: Because each of those bits controls an output pin, and each output pin probably controls a relay to switch the motor power supply one way or the other, since you can't drive an electric motor directly from TTL logic circuit.

Comment: what is the main function of relay in this experiment? @Weather Vane

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, except possibly to control the motor, as I said.